# What does this symbol mean $f(A \cap B)?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, symbolic-computation

What does  $f(A \cap B)?$ mean. Is it a set, function , polynomial, etc? What are the characteristics in its structure? what does this mean in detail?

Comment: are A and B sequences? Too little context provided.Anyway $\cap$ is the intersection symbol.

Comment: @sarah: What are $A,B$ (my guess is that you meant sets) and $f$ (a normal function)? Please be more specific!

Answer (score 2):

If $f:X\to Y$ is a function, and if $Z\subseteq X$ is a subset, then $f\left(Z\right)=\left\{f\left(z\right)\middle| z\in Z\right\}$ is a set.

In this case, given $A,B\subseteq X$, then $f\left(A\cap B\right)$ is a set.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably like this (although the context is necessary to be absolutely sure):

- $f$ is a function that takes a set as input (for example a [measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics))).
- $A$ and $B$ are sets
- $A \cap B$ is the [intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)) which is a set itself (potentially the empty set).

It can also be that $f$ is any function and it is the set of all values returned by inputting all values of $A\cap B$ into $f$, i.e. 
$$ f(A\cap B)=\{f(x)\mid x \in A \cap B\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$f(A\cap B) = \{f(x) : x \in A\cap B \}$